# What does the "pop" function do when I'm editing a photo?

Tags: google-photos, image-manipulation

I'm trying to edit picture in [photos.google](https://photos.google.com/).

When I press edit I see the following:

[image]

I understand what is **Light** and **Color**, but what is **Pop**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The pop effect is simply an increase in local contrast.](https://www.quora.com/How-can-the-pop-effect-on-Google-photos-be-done-on-photoshop)

Comment: why just not call it contrast?